# javascript prototype not outputing to html

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying out constructors and prototypes in javascript for the first time. From what I've heard and read online, it's the best approach to creating multiple instances of the object so that I don't have to write the same code over and over again.

I have a div element in my index.html file with a class of ancillary that I would like to output to. So far when I run the code, I don't get any errors but it also outputs nothing. What I'm I doing wrong? Please Help! Thanks

```
function AncillaryBox(explanation, type, element) {
    this.explanation = explanation;
    this.type = type;
    this.element = $('.ancillary');
};

AncillaryBox.prototype.renderElement = function() {
    if (this.type === 'bible-dive') {
        var title = 'Bible Dive';
        var initial = 'B';
    } else if (this.type === 'word-studies') {
        var title = 'Word Studies';
        var initial = 'W';
    } else if (this.type === 'bible-translations') {
        var title = 'In Other Words';
        var initial = 'I';
    }

    $('.ancillary').html('<div class="' + this.type + 'icon' + '>' + '<span>' + this.initial + '</span>' + '</div>');
};

var uncleanness = new AncillaryBox("Being considered unclean in Hebrew culture was a big deal. There were a few levels of uncleanness, each with certain steps for cleansing. Steps ranged from just washing oneself and one’s clothes, to exclusion from society for awhile. And you thought cleaning your room was a pain!", "bible-dive");

uncleanness.renderElement();
```

Comment: I see you're also using jQuery - do you have your `$(document).ready()` in place? Also, `this.initial` is not set to anything.

Comment: Works as expected, simple typo - you are missing a `"` which is preventing the rendering of the HTML, change to `$('.ancillary').html('<div class="' + this.type + 'icon' + '">' + '<span>' + initial + '</span>' + '</div>');`

Comment: Yes I'm using jQuery, I don't have document.ready() in place because I in my html file, I linked to jQuery at the bottom of my body element and then linked to app.js below that which is where the code above is.

Comment: Also note you have `var initial` and `this.initial`

Comment: should I take off 'this' "

Comment: as per Alex K's feedback, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u94quamx/

Comment: @ohenecoker yes, remove the `this`, as that means look at the instance of AncillaryBox, which doesn't have a property called initial.

Comment: Nice it works!! Thank you guys so much!!